# vb.net Keydown event on whole form

Tags: vb.net, keydown

I have a form with several controls. I want to run a specific sub on keydown event regardless any controls event.
I mean if user press Ctrl+S anywhere on form it execute a subroutine.

Answer (score 22):

You should set the [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property on the form to True and handle the keydown event there

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus. .......... To handle keyboard
>   events only at the form level and not allow controls to receive
>   keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your
>   form's KeyPress event handler to true.

So, for example, to handle the Control+S key combination you could write this event handler for the form KeyDown event.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If  e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S then
        ' Call your sub method here  .....
        YourSubToCall()

        ' then prevent the key to reach the current control
        e.Handled = False 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Steve... its very helpful

Answer (score 3):

I've used this code in my forms before and it seems to work pretty good.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessKeyPreview(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean
    If m.Msg = &H100 Then  'WM_KEYDOWN
        Dim key As Keys = m.WParam
        If key = Keys.S And My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then 
             'DO stuff
             Return True
        End If
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessKeyPreview(m)
 End Function
```