# VB.Net KeyDown Event on Form

Tags: vb.net

How do i make a KeyDown event for a Form?

When I have the application open, I want to know when I type certain keys to display a message.

```
   Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            MsgBox("enter key pressd ")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [vb.net Keydown event on whole form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727172/vb-net-keydown-event-on-whole-form)?

[KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_KeyPreview) property should be set to `True` on the form.

Code used in answer (not what you want to do exactly):

```vb
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If  e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S then
        ' Call your sub method here  .....
        YourSubToCall()

        ' then prevent the key to reach the current control
        e.Handled = False 
    End If
End Sub
```